# Change initial token to vnode in Cassandra 2.1.7

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

Currently I am running Cassandra cluster with 4 nodes with initial token range.
It has not been repaired since long time due to gc failed.

Now, I want to change initial token to vnode (num token).
What should I do?
1. Shall I run 'nodetool repair' and then change initial toke to vnode?
2. Shall I change initial token to vnode first and then run 'nodetool repair' ?
3. Do I need to run 'nodetool repair' on all the node or on any one node?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot directly convert a single-token nodes to a vnode. However,
>   you can configure another datacenter configured with vnodes already
>   enabled and let Cassandra automatic mechanisms distribute the existing
>   data into the new nodes. This method has the least impact on
>   performance.

[Existing cluster to vNodes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configVnodesProduction.html)

Nodetool repair will have to be ran on each node and doing with advanced option -pr will be helpful

`nodetool repair -pr`

Comment: run `nodetool repair -pr` on one node at a time